# EditText space characters to break line?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spaces

I have a multiline EditText.

Whenever the input text is reaching its maximum width, the line breaks and the text is moving
to the next line.

However, it isn't working well with spaces. 
When there is an input like "blabla" and then lots of spaces, the line not breaks and the text
is being pushed to the left until it "goes out" of the EditText.

How can I treat the spaces as "regular" characters for it to work?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion convert it to html plain text. i mean

```
edittext.settext(Html.fromhtml(your text));
```

i hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to replace all spaces by newline?

```
String test = "";
test = your_et.getText().toString();
test.replaceAll(" ", "\n");
your_et.setText(test);
```